# Create a DataGridViewCheckBoxCell in DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagridviewcheckboxcell

I contact you because I have a problem in my C# program.

I am using a basic DataGridView with four DataGridViewTextBoxColumn. And I would like to add a checkbox with a label in the first cell of the data grid view at the position Row[0]/Column[0].

I try this :

```
DataGridViewCell ch1 = new DataGridViewCheckBoxCell();
this.dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0] = ch1;
```

But it is not working and I have an exception concerning the type of the cell when I run the application.

I would like to know if the thing that I want to do is possible ? By which way ?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: you will have to create a DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn instead of DataGridViewTextBoxColumn if you want checkboxes